# How do I remove all lines in a file that are less than 6 characters?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file containing approximately 10 million lines.

I want to remove all lines in the file that are less than six characters.

How do I do this?

Comment: Isn't this question more suited for Stackoverflow?

Comment: @user1073075 it is perfectly on-topic here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

Using `grep`:

```
grep -E '^.{6,}$' file.txt >out.txt
```

Now `out.txt` will contain lines having six or more characters.

Reverse way:

```
grep -vE '^.{,5}$' file.txt >out.txt
```

---

Using `sed`, removing lines of length 5 or less:

```
sed -r '/^.{,5}$/d' file.txt
```

Reverse way, printing lines of length six or more:

```
sed -nr '/^.{6,}$/p' file.txt
```

You can save the output in a different file using `>` operator like `grep` or edit the file in-place using `-i` option of `sed`:

```
sed -ri.bak '/^.{6,}$/' file.txt
```

The original file will be backed up as `file.txt.bak` and the modified file will be `file.txt`.

If you do not want to keep a backup:

```
sed -ri '/^.{6,}$/' file.txt
```

---

Using shell, **Slower, Don't do this**, this is just for the sake of showing another method:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line; do [ "${#line}" -ge 6 ] && echo "$line"; done <file.txt
```

---

Using `python`,even  slower than `grep`, `sed`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.rstrip('\n')) >= 6:
            print line.rstrip('\n')
```

Better use list comprehension to be more Pythonic:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.txt') as f:
     strip = str.rstrip
     print '\n'.join([line for line in f if len(strip(line, '\n')) >= 6]).rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: Yay! I was hoping for a python answer **=)**

Comment: @DevRobot I see..then check out list comprehension i added, be more Pythonic..

Comment: Also @DevRobot not so sure python is slower on huge files, when the first option is used. Actually I am pretty sure python is faster on millions of lines, since it reads per line.

Comment: The second python example reads the whole file into memory before doing the join. I think the first python example is better in this instance.

Comment: Reading by lines is necessarily slower because files are not structured like that. You need to read a block ahead anyway and search for a newline with reduced possibilities of parallelization, then return only the partial string. You need a circular buffer. You need to allocate memory dynamically if you don't know how long the lines can be.

Comment: @heemayl You should be using a generator comprehension, not a list comprehension. Also, do `line.rstrip('\n')`, don't create an unnecessary local. In fact, don't do `line.rstrip`, you don't have to strip the lines at all if you just end up joining them on a newline anyway. `with open('file.txt') as f: print(''.join(line for line in f if len(line.rstrip('\n')) >= 6))`

Comment: @VašekPotoček I can't quite get the story you're trying to tell, but on huge files, per line is faster. *Not* reading per line implies loading the whole file, will choke your system and might even be impossible when the files are really big.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Reading the whole file was not the alternative I had in mind. Rather, reading it by blocks, say 1024 B, and operating upon these without artificial splitting into lines where unnecessary.

Answer (score 20):

It's very simple:

```
grep ...... inputfile > resultfile   #There are 6 dots
```

This is extremely efficient, as `grep` will not try to parse more than it needs, nor to interpret the chars in any way: it simply send a (whole) line to stdout (which the shell then redirects to resultfile) *as soon as* it saw 6 chars on that line (`.` in a regexp context matches any 1 character).

So grep will only output lines having 6 (or more) chars, and the other ones are not outputted by grep so they don't make it to resultfile.

Answer (score 15):

#### Solution #1: using C

Fastest way: compile and run this C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int length;

    if(argc == 3)
        length = atoi(argv[2]);
    else
        return 1;

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(file != NULL) {
        char line[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
            char *pos;

            if((pos = strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL)
                *pos = '\0';
            if(strlen(line) >= length)
                printf("%s\n", line);
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `gcc program.c -o program`, run with `./program file line_length` (where `file` = path to the file and `line_length` = minimum line length, in your case `6`; the maximum line length is limited to `1000000` characters per line; you can change this by changing the value of `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE`).

(Trick to substitute `\n` with `\0` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693826/4316166).)

Comparison with all the other solutions proposed to this question except the shell solution (test run on a ~91MB file with 10M lines with an average lenght of 8 characters):

```
time ./foo file 6

real    0m1.592s
user    0m0.712s
sys 0m0.160s

time grep ...... file

real    0m1.945s
user    0m0.912s
sys 0m0.176s

time grep -E '^.{6,}$'

real    0m2.178s
user    0m1.124s
sys 0m0.152s

time awk 'length>=6' file

real    0m2.261s
user    0m1.228s
sys 0m0.160s

time perl -lne 'length>=6&&print' file

real    0m4.252s
user    0m3.220s
sys 0m0.164s

sed -r '/^.{,5}$/d' file >out

real    0m7.947s
user    0m7.064s
sys 0m0.120s

./script.py >out
real    0m8.154s
user    0m7.184s
sys 0m0.164s
```

---

#### Solution #2: using AWK:

```
awk 'length>=6' file
```

- `length>=6`: if `length>=6` returns TRUE, prints the current record.

---

#### Solution #3: using Perl:

```
perl -lne 'length>=6&&print' file
```

- If `lenght>=6` returns TRUE, prints the current record.

---

```
% cat file
a
bb
ccc
dddd
eeeee
ffffff
ggggggg
% ./foo file 6
ffffff
ggggggg
% awk 'length>=6' file   
ffffff
ggggggg
% perl -lne 'length>=6&&print' file
ffffff
ggggggg
```

Comment: Believe me..I was waiting for _your_ `awk` solution..

Comment: @heemayl And I didn't saw the question immediately, so I *knew* that if you happened to be online you would have been faster. Had to delete my `sed` solution (it happens, I know). XD

Comment: What is the point of the `pos` variable?  I get it returns a pointer to the character  in `line` with a newline character, but you never seem to use it.  And if you don't find it, you just set it equal to `\0`.

Comment: @user1717828 If I *find* it I replace it with `\0` (`strchr()` returns a NULL pointer if the character *isn't* found). The point is replacing each newline at the end of each line with `\0` so that the newline is never counted by `strlen()`: this is so that the lenght can always be compared to 6 regardless of a potential missing newline on the last line. Treating differently only the last line would be way more efficient, I know. I'll probably update this later.

Comment: Factoring in the compilaton time, the C solution is probably slower for a one-off job.  For a beginner who is not familiar with `gcc` etc, it will be *much* more efficient to simply stick with the simple, obvious `grep` solution, which also will not suffer from limitations like the fixed line buffer size you used, as well as possibly less obvious but more crippling bugs.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it would lose the tail end of a line which was 1000002 characters long.

Comment: @tripleee The idea was to add a solution useful for something more than a one-time job, or for even bigger files, *but*: I tested the `grep` solution on the same file and it's actually faster (probably because `strlen()` is not the best idea here). I'll try to use a `getchar()` loop in order to check only the first N character instead, I guess that should improve it visibly. And yes, any line over the buffer's lenght is simply cut to the buffer's length.

Comment: @tripleee I probably messed up something while testing: the C solution is actually slightly faster than the `grep` solution. However there's room for improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'v/\v.{6}/d' -cx file
```

1. `\v` turn on magic
2. `.{6}` find lines with 6 or more characters
3. `v` invert selection
4. `d` delete
5. `x` save and close

Answer (score 2):

Ruby solution:

```
$ cat input.txt                                                                                                          
abcdef
abc
abcdefghijk

$ ruby -ne 'puts $_ if $_.chomp.length() >= 6 ' < input.txt                                                              
abcdef
abcdefghijk
```

Simple idea: redirect file into ruby's stdin, and print line from stdin only if it's length greater or equal to 6